# What's another, neutral, way to call someone who continues a story?

Tags: single-word-requests, titles, story

I am trying to label someone who plays roles in a story; for example, I want someone who makes the story happen. Beginning, middle, and end. I have Creator and Destroyer, but I need something in the middle that doesn't carry a negative connotation. I'm using aggravator, but that's negative.

Comment: Maybe they are *plot motivators*

Comment: It's a good overall term, Plot motivators, but there there needs to be a specific term for each section as they are different sections in my paper. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In Hindu theology the three main Gods (or Trinity if you prefer) are [Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/mug-up). Brahma is The Creator, Shiva is the Destroyer and Vishnu is the Protector or **Sustainer**.

Depending on the nature of your story 'Sustainer' may well fit as the echoes of Hindu thought might give the whole story extra resonance.

Comment: I really like this. My character analysis is Loki, God of Mischief, so the mythical connection is interesting. He's purpose revolves around him and the progression of stories.

Comment: @S.Watt Glad you like it! Is Loki both the Creator and Destroyer or are they other characters?

Answer (score 0):

## How about "continuer" or "sustenant?"

sustenant
ADJECTIVE

literary 
Offering sustenance or support; sustaining.
Origin
Late 19th century ; earliest use found in Mortimer Collins (1827–1876), novelist and journalist. From sustenance: see -ant.

OxfordDictionaries.com

Note to @BoldBen: Your suggestion has merit, too, and it's interesting. Reframe it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you! My old Dean of A&S suggested something along the same lines.

Answer (score 0):

Someone who makes the story happen sounds like a ***protagonist***.

Wikipedia:

> A ***[protagonist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protagonist)*** (from Ancient Greek πρωταγωνιστής (protagonistes),
>   meaning "player of the first part, chief actor") is **the main character
>   in any story**, such as a literary work or drama.
>
> The **protagonist is at the center of the story**, should be making the
>   difficult choices and key decisions, and should be experiencing the
>   consequences of those decisions. **The protagonist should be propelling
>   the story forward**.